# Having problems with JQuery function in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have written a jQuery function which calls a c# method.

If the function returns a success then it calls another method from the c# code which is responsible for incrementing the counter variable in my c# class.

I wanted to do automatic counter increment every 1 minute and this is what I noticed. I set up a breakpoint in my Counter() function in my c# class. As the page loads up and the Counter method is called, I proceed with my debugging and notice that things work fine but once the counter variable reaches the value "2", when I press F10 to step into my Counter method(), it doesn't reach the end of the method and increments the counter variable by 2 and then from here on things get worse.

I wonder what could I be doing wrong? Can anyone review my script and give me suggestions on what could be causing the error?

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Dtata.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dtata" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        klm();

        function klm() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dtata.aspx/Hello",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{ 'name' : 'hello' }",
            success: function(result) {
              console.log(result.d);
              Counter() //<-- CALL OTHER AJAX METHOD TO INCREASE COUNTER ON BACK END
            },
            error: function(result) {
              alert(result.responseText);
            }
          });
        }


        function Counter() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dtata.aspx/Counter",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(result) {
              console.log(result.d);
            },
            error: function(result) {
              alert(result.responseText);
            }
          });
          setInterval(Counter, 60000);


        }
      </script>



    </form>


  </body>
  </html
```

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Dtata: System.Web.UI.Page {
  public static int counter = 0;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {


  }

  [WebMethod]
  public static string Hello(string name) {
    return name;
  }

  [WebMethod]
  public static int Counter() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    Console.WriteLine("I have been called" + counter);

    return counter;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing. You call counter in klm and also in setInterval.

If you want to loop an AJAX function, instead do this:

```
function Counter() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Dtata.aspx/Counter",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result.d);
      setTimeout(Counter,60000); // call again if ok - or in .done
    },
    error: function(result) {
      alert(result.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

Another thing - I would expect your C# to read and write the counter to a DB and I do not see the C# return any JSON with a `{ d:counter}`